# Dealing with height and width overflow

Tags: css, overflow, centering

Given an image, I would like to lock the width at 426px, and adjust the height
as needed.

Regarding the height, I only want to see the centermost 240px of the image.
Regarding the width, I would like the full width visible, but if the screen is
too narrow, then view as much of the width from the center as possible. I have
this as a start:

```html
<style>
figure {
   border: medium solid red;
   height: 240px;
   max-width: 426px;
}
img {
   width: 426px;
}
</style>
<figure>
   <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/xMzpFTcT4eg/sddefault.jpg">
</figure>
```

but the image is not centered, it is locked at the top. Is it possible to
vertically center the image, hiding height overflow, while also hiding width
overflow if needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) should does the trick.

```html
<style>
figure {
   border: medium solid red;
   height: 240px;
   max-width: 426px;
   
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
   justify-content: center;
   overflow: hidden;
}
img {
   width: 426px;
}
</style>
<figure>
   <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/xMzpFTcT4eg/sddefault.jpg">
</figure>
```

Comment: that is close, but when you put it with a narrow screen, it just scales down rather than hiding width

Comment: Then img {flex-shrink: 0;} will do.

Comment: @VXp yes that fixes it!

Answer (score 0):

This seems to do it:

```html
<style>
figure {
   border: medium solid red;
   height: 240px;
   max-width: 426px;
   overflow: hidden;
}
img {
   left: 50%;
   position: relative;
   top: 50%;
   transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
   width: 426px;
}
</style>
<figure>
   <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/xMzpFTcT4eg/sddefault.jpg">
</figure>
```

if anyone has better method, please let me know.